# Facebook directs to blank page after giving permission

Tags: facebook

I am using social connect on my website, when I try to connect using my facebook account, the popup shows the permission screen, and when I click "allow", it directs me to a blank page...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably navigating the page while opening the dialog - this will happen if you for instance use a form submit button or an anchor with an onclick to execute `FB.login`.

Comment: If this is it, `return false;` is the fix.